# Screen goes blank when starting media, ubuntu 20.04 xps 7390 2-in-1

Tags: dell, 20.04, xps

After updating my Dell Xps 7390 2-in-1 from ubuntu 19.10 to ubuntu 20.04, the screen goes blank always when starting a video, either youtube or local file, for about 2 seconds. Possibly the same goes for any media.

It will also go blank at random times with no particular reason.

My xps has an Iris plus integrated graphics card and a i7-1065G7 cpu.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar laptop (Dell XPS 13 9300) and I had the same issue. I found 2 solutions.

1st - Make sure your bios is up to date. (This fixed it for me)

2nd - Use a more recent kernel, I heard from someone else with the same issue said 5.5.19 kernel worked for him, but I had wifi issues, but with 5.6.14 I didn't have noticeable issues. So just experiment to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and ran into the same problem. It seems they enabled Panel Self Refresh by default, causing this problem on certain audio signals, so the screen goes black when playing a video or for me even when I adjusted the volume. The solution described here: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-13-7390-Ubuntu-Screen-flickering/td-p/7430121 solved this issue for me.

Comment: In my case the problem was solved with an update to the kernel libraries. It hasn't occurred until now.